# Excel VBA extract price after specific word

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, extract

I need to scrape item price from Amazon page.
Using VBA code Htmldoc.GetElementById("price") I get this output:

RRP:£36.00
Price:£25.00 (£35.71 / l) & FREE Delivery . Delivery Details
You Save:£11.00 (31%)

But is there a way to extract only price which is 25.00 in this example?
I know how to do it with FIND formula by key word 'Price:' if text posted to cell, but in this case it has to be done in VBA only.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split like that

```
Sub Test()
    Dim s As String
    s = "RRP:£36.00 Price:£25.00 (£35.71 / l) & FREE Delivery . Delivery Details You Save:£11.00 (31%)"
    Debug.Print "Price = " & Split(Split(s, "Price:")(1))(0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! Thanks YasserKahil this option worked as well :)

Answer (score 0):

As you probably wish the numeric price, you can use *Val*:

```vb
PriceInfo = "RRP:£36.00 Price:£25.95 (£35.71 / l) & FREE Delivery . Delivery Details You Save:£11.00 (31%)"
Price = Val(Split(PriceInfo, "Price:£")(1))
? Price 
 25.95
```